# Avoiding duplicating PeriodicWorkRequest from WorkManager

Tags: android, android-workmanager

On Application start I want to start service that will work forever, but when user opens app again it duplicates.

```
PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder sendDataBuilder = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(SendConnectionMetricsWorker.class, Constants.REPEAT_TIME_INTERVAL_IN_HOURS, Constants.REPEAT_TIME_INTERVAL_UNITS)
                .setConstraints(new Constraints.Builder()
                        .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                        .build());
        PeriodicWorkRequest periodicWorkRequest = sendDataBuilder
                .build();
        WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(periodicWorkRequest);
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use `enqueueUniquePeriodicWork` instead of `enqueue`. Based on the documentation:

> This method allows you to enqueue a uniquely-named
>   PeriodicWorkRequest, where only one PeriodicWorkRequest of a
>   particular name can be active at a time. For example, you may only
>   want one sync operation to be active. **If there is one pending, you can
>   choose to let it run or replace it with your new work. The
>   uniqueWorkName uniquely identifies this PeriodicWorkRequest.**

You can achieve it as follows:

```
PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder sendDataBuilder = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(SendConnectionMetricsWorker.class, Constants.REPEAT_TIME_INTERVAL_IN_HOURS, Constants.REPEAT_TIME_INTERVAL_UNITS)
                .setConstraints(new Constraints.Builder()
                        .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                        .build());
 PeriodicWorkRequest periodicWorkRequest = sendDataBuilder
                .build();
 WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("Send Data",  ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP,periodicWorkRequest);
```

**Note:**

`ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE` ensures that if there is pending work labelled with uniqueWorkName, it will be cancelled and the new work will run. `ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP` will run the new PeriodicWorkRequest only if there is no pending work labelled with uniqueWorkName.

Comment: enqueueUniquePeriodicWork()? Which version of library do you use? I guess I don't have this method

Comment: @IhorKostenko iam using `implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-alpha03"` . You can refer [official document](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components#workmanager) for more details

Comment: Thanks, I was on alpha02 and it had different API )

Comment: @Sagar with this new enqueueUniquePeriodicWork we do not need anymore to check the workstatus and observe the liveData event, right?

Comment: @NicolasJafelle You mean check the status before scheduling? If this one then yes. By using appropriate `ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy` OS will take care of necessary actions

Comment: @Sagar I am doing this:
        WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(TAG,
                ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP,
                sendMessageWork);

So if there is a periodic worker scheduled with that TAG unique name the workmanager simple ignore future enqueueUniquePeriodicWork, right? Unless I replace KEEP with REPLACE.

Comment: @NicolasJafelle based on the documentation, yes. You need consider that its still in alpha release. If you found any issues, remember to file it to Google.

Comment: @Sagar, in this case `WorkManager.getInstance().cancelUniqueWork("Send Data")` will cancel all the future occurrence as well or only the next one??

Comment: Getting cannot resolve symbol error on import java.time.Duration in PeriodicWorkRequest class. I am on java 1.8.

Comment: my "enqueueUniquePeriodicWork" does only work(sync data) a few times. After that it does not sync anymore, even with KEEP or REPLACE policy, no constraints... Any idea?

Comment: @DanAlboteanu I have the same question here if you ever figured it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68259689/workmanager-periodic-work-is-not-running-periodically